# Can you use multiple SRV records with the same target?

Tags: dns

I'm looking at running multiple game servers on the same IP with different ports. The way I imagined it working was something like this:

**SRV records:**
_service._tcp.game-name-1 => 10 5 [port1] server-pc.domain.com
_service._tcp.game-name-2 => 10 5 [port2] server-pc.domain.com

**A record:**
server-pc.domain.com => IPV4 Address

I want to set it up this way to be able to change the IPV4 address without going through multiple A records. I also tried using CNAMES pointing to the server-pc A record, but this also seems to not be working. I may just be misunderstanding how SRV's work, but I would assume I could set the same target as long as the port is different, which is what I want. Is this actually possible or am I just misunderstanding something?

[image: Current SRV and A records]